# Grafana query for a particular tag Property under metric.counter

Tags: grafana, graphite

Getting count of the value for below

```
Metrics.counter("example.action.update", Arrays.asList(
        Tag.of("exampleStatus", update.getActionStatus().name())
    )).increment()
```

```
currentAbove(aliasByNode(atl.stg.k8s.xpp.response-update-listener.response_action_update.application.deviceId.*.status.STARTED,9), 0)
```

I need `exampleStatus` value under Grafana to check if is greater than zero. The metrics are stored in the Graphite database.

Can anybody mention Grafana query to do the same?

Comment: which timeline db are you using for storing your metrics?

Comment: @JensBaitinger

Graphite db is used to store metrics